# Start Time and End Time with freq or percentage

Tags: excel, sas, excel-2010, vba

I have a data which has a start time, end time, Stay Time(End-Start) and # of subjects. I am trying to create a graph, line, bar or histogram which shows how many subjects were there at a specific time. So the horizontal axis would have time from 00:00 to 24:00 and vertical axis would have the total # of subjects or the %.

```
Start    End    Subject    Stay
01:00    02:00    1        01:00
01:00    01:45    1        00:45
02:00    21:00    1        19:00
03:10    14:10    1        11:00
```

The data set is huge and I am using SAS Enterprise Guide and excel to create a graph.

I have tried PROC GPLOT but it doesn't provide me what I am looking for. Did the same thing for line plots and bar charts(stacked) but couldn't. I am not sure if there is an easier way to do it . This is a code I used in SAS EG. Tried creating a stacked bar chart in excel as well.

```
PROC GPLOT DATA=Input;
PLOT Stay * start  /
AREAS=1
FRAME   VAXIS=AXIS1
HAXIS=AXIS2
;

RUN; QUIT;
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to transform your data to create one row for each time period you were looking at (hour, for example, if you wanted to show # of people who were present at any point during each hour).

You can do something like this:

```
data want;
set have;
do time=intnx('Hour',start,0) to end by 3600; *start at top of current hour, increment by 1 hour (3600 seconds);
  output;
end;
run;
```

Then you can graph the `time` variable in a bar chart.

Your data may be a problem for some of these approaches (such as ETS) because you're using overlapping periods - you have subject 1 having 4 stays that overlap heavily.  If these are different days you might want to add a day marker to the subject to make them unique.

Example using your data:

```
data have;
input Start :time5. End :time5. Subject Stay :time5.;
format start end stay time5.;
datalines;
01:00    02:00    1        01:00
01:00    01:45    2        00:45
02:00    21:00    2        19:00
03:10    14:10    3        11:00
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
do hour_mark = intnx('Hour',start,0) to end by 3600;
 output;
end;
keep hour_mark subject;
format hour_mark time5.;
run;

proc sgplot data=want;
vbar hour_mark;
run;
```

You could run the same example using a more interesting dataset:

```
data have;
if _n_=1 then call streaminit(7);
do subject = 1 to 100;
    start=floor(rand('Uniform')*86000);*almost all day, but make sure we have a bit of room for end;
    end  =floor(rand('Uniform')*(86400-start))+start;
    stay=end-start;
    output;
end;
format start end stay time5.;
run;
```

and then use the same WANT and SGPLOT code.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I already have a column like that. I added a condition that if Start is between 0-1 then 1. Like that. I know that's not the best way to do it. I tried your code and it gives me this error-"ERROR: Invalid DO loop control information, either the INITIAL or TO expression is missing or the BY expression is missing, zero, 
       or invalid."

Comment: Tried using PROC EXPAND - proc expand data=Input out=output from=minute to=hour ;
 id start;
 by start;
 convert subject / method=aggregate observed=average;
 run;  /* got this error - "ERROR: Observation with duplicate ID value found. The value of the ID variable, start=0:04:00, at observation number 2 in data set 
       input is the same as the previous observation."

Comment: I don't understand your first comment.  You show data that has one row for 02:00 to 21:00.  I suggest you need 19 or 20 rows for that (depending on how you define things).  Is your data not like that?

Comment: I added examples.  I'm not sure about EXPAND; I thought it did this specifically fairly easily, but looking at it more I'm not sure it would be useful without a bit more work which is basically duplicating the other method.